# php how to display friends based on zipcode?

Tags: php, proximity

i have a database with some names and addresses, zip codes, etc

i am looking for a way to display names close to a zipcode.

something like based on my zip code to show the people with in my proximity

i am looking for an script idea...

i know google has something but it charges after 50.000 entries

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it.

Download the zipcode database with latitutde/longitude [here](http://databases.about.com/od/access/a/zipcodedatabase.htm).

Do a query in mysql to get users close to x miles.

Luckily, someone has already [written a library to do all this for you](http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-zip-code-range-and-distance-calculation.html).